# JQuery problem in Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, drop-down-menu

I have a Problem with Jquery dropdown and Firefox.

Thats the situation: 
in the index.html there is a dropdown selection with 3 options. Each of theme has a html file.
In the second dropdown there is again 3 Options after i select the first dropdown.

The Problem is in the second Dropdown.
Firefox always takes the last  from the file. Internet-Explorer just does it fine.

I hope someone can help me, and sorry because my english, :-S

i uploaded the files in a zip if anybody could help me...
[link](http://rapidshare.com/files/310337036/jquery.zip.html)

Comment: You'll probably get a better response if you post the code in your question, rather than linking to a zip file.

Comment: I downloaded the file and looked at the code and I can't see any problems.  Can you clarify what the problem you are having is?

Comment: Rapidshare download session expired.....

Answer (score 1):

Use a callback function to select the first drop-down option after loading the external content.

Modified index.html line 108:

```
$("select[name=ajax2]").load(datei + " option", null, ajax1Callback);
```

Add this to index.html line 126:

```
function ajax1Callback() {
    $('SELECT[name=ajax2]').val(0);
}
```

Comment: +1 This should fix your problem... also remove the `$("#ajax2").append(result).selectedIndex = 0;` - it's for an ID that doesn't exist and a `result` variable that is not defined.

Comment: That was it. Greate, thank you. I was wondering if you also know, why the select option in the first dropdown can't load the extern code for the second dropdown. Only if i change in the first dropdown to a other option, than it works. 

That happens also if i go back in browser history, and i want to klick the option wich already is selected.

Comment: You could try setting a cookie with the user's selected value using `$.cookie`, then in `ajax1Callback()` set the val to the selected option.

Comment: hm how? Sorry i am new :-S 
could you explane that to me? Witch line, what code?

Comment: Using the JQuery cookie extension http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-cookies/ you can save a cookie when a user makes a selection from a drop-down `('SELECT').click(function() { $.cookie('selected', $(this).val()); })` then check for the cookie in `ajax1Callback` like this `$('SELECT[name=ajax2]').val(0, $.cookie('selected'));`